# Table Latex : add lines and center the caption

Tags: tables, captions, cell

I'm a beginner user of Latex , i wana drow a table but i got this

[image]

i wana add the lines between the rows, also the caption in the center and  expand the cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
      \centering  
      \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|*{4}{c|}}\hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Algorithme} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries 2-hop} \\\cline{2-5} & \textbf{node}       & \textbf{true?} \\ \hline
        R-ELM         & Normal              & No             \\ \hline
        Q-ELM         & Normal              & No             \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{some table}
      \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please, extend your code snipped to small but complete document beginning with ˙`\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In preamble load only necessary packages.

Comment: What you want is not clear. You declare 5 columns but write 3. Further, the caption is centred by default, so there must be something in the ret of your code which does that.

Comment: see, if `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c| *{2}{c|} }
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Algorithme} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{2-hop}}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
                & \textbf{node} & \textbf{true?}        \\ \hline
    R-ELM       & Normal        & No                    \\ \hline
    Q-ELM       & Normal        & No                    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{some table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
` gives what you want.

Comment: @Zarko thank you so mush , i wana also expand the cells width , Can you help?

Comment: how to expand cells? cells' widths are (now) determined with their content, however You can increase columns separation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array, multirow} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{18pt}% default value is 6pt 
    \centering 
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c| *{2}{c|} } 
    \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Algorithme} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{2-hop}}   \\ 
    \cline{2-3}                          
                            & \textbf{node} & \textbf{true?}        \\ 
    \hline
        R-ELM               & Normal    & No                        \\ 
    \hline Q-ELM            & Normal    & No                        \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
    \caption{some table} 
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```